# Resources for learning multithreading using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am looking for a resource (web/book) to learn concurrent programming with C#, specifically something that focuses on memory model, sharing data between threads, synchronization, fine grained locking, mutex, semaphore, waithandle etc.

I know I can find these in msdn, but I would prefer something presented in a step by step manner.

Could you please suggest a recommended resource?

Comment: Use both the free book advised by Nicholas and try to see implementation/usage possibilities by the latest .NET framework (link).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you start with Joe Albahari's [free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Then get Joe Duffy's [Concurrent Programming on Windows](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/books/winconc/winconc_book_resources.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at .NET framework 4.5:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/17/10212961.aspx